# How to calculate levels occurrence of factor column?

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(
    cola = c('1','b','c','1','1','e','1',NA,'c','d'),
    colb = c("A",NA,"C","D",'a','b','c','d','c','d'),
    colc = c('a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','c','d'),stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

`df$cola` is `1    b    c    1    1    e    1    <NA> c    d`
I want to know how many `1` in this column(answer is 4),how to do it?

Comment: `length(which(df$cola == 1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `sum` here:

```
num_ones <- sum(df$cola == "1", na.rm=TRUE)
num_ones

[1] 4
```

The `na.rm=TRUE` option is needed, because without it, the entire `sum` operation would "NA out", and just return `NA`.  In this case, we can just ignore `NA` values.

Comment: `sum(df$cola %in% "1")` would also work here.

Comment: @jay.sf It might also depend on the brand of `cola`.  I prefer Coke over Pepsi, for obvious reasons :P

Comment: You should really try VIVI Cola, it's a Swiss cola brewed with water from the Alps :)